How to view older Azure Devops Agent job logs
When viewing jobs that have run on a self-hosted Azure Devops Agent the list of jobs appears to be capped at about the 50 most recent jobs.
I need to be able to view jobs from up to 10 days ago. Is this possible via the web interface?  If not, is it possible to view them another way?
In Azure Devops, when viewing the pipeline job logs, how can I view older logs? Specifically I need to be able to view older logs for a specific agent for audit and performance analysis. Currently if i view the logs for single agent the jobs only go back 50 or so jobs

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

in Azure Devops, when viewing the pipeline job logs, how can I view older logs? Specifically I need to be able to view older logs for a specific agent for audit and performance analysis. Currently if i view the logs for single agent the jobs only go back 50 or so jobs.
